# How does PathLib Works

Tags: python, pathlib

I was using Pathlib on Python3.x and I found a piece of code that got me curious.

```
from pathlib import Path
BASE = Path('/mydir').resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
print( BASE / 'Sub-dir')
```

And that works perfectly, printing out:

```
/mydir/Sub-dir
```

I got curious to understand how that works, if someone could help me out.
Regards

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Start off by using it. Later on you can worry about how it works...

Comment: I just got curious of how Python interprets the instance of Path class and adds the subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It implements the [`__truediv()__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__truediv__) method.

From https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pathlib.py

```
def __truediv__(self, key):
    try:
        return self._make_child((key,))
    except TypeError:
        return NotImplemented
```

`__truediv()__` defines how the division operator `/` works with objects of the class. In this case, it makes a child path with the second operand

Comment: So basically this changes the original functionality of __truediv()__ method?

Comment: I just saw your comment @LuccaLemeMarques. There's no _original_ functionality. You give it that functionality (the ability to participate in an expression of the form `a / b`) by implementing the method.